# How to pass selected item from dropdown list to controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, devexpress

I have a dropdown list of values which the user is able to select from. The GetCobDates method works to return my list for the dropdown menu. I am trying to pass the selected value from the list to the controller in my form with the submit button, but it's passing null. Please see my relevant code below:

```
            <form action="@Url.Action("QueueFileUpload","Home")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="start-process">
                <div class="dx-field-value">
                    @(Html.DevExtreme().DropDownButton()
                                .Text("Select COB Date")

                                .Icon("save")
                                .DropDownOptions(options => options.Width(230))
                                .DataSource(ds => ds.Mvc()
                                                        .Controller("Home")
                                                        .Key("Id")
                                                        .LoadAction("GetCobDates"))

                                .OnItemClick("downloadButton_click")

                    )
                    @(Html.DevExtreme().Button()
                                .ID("submit")
                                .Text("Submit")
                                .Type(ButtonType.Default)
                                .UseSubmitBehavior(true)
                                .Icon(Url.Content("~/favicon.ico"))

                    )
                </div>

            </form>


            //JQuery function

            <script>
            function downloadButton_click(e) {
                DevExpress.ui.notify("Data from COB Date of " + e.itemData + " selected", "info", 1500);
            return e;
            }

            </script>
```

Controller:

```
  public void QueueFileUpload(int cobID)
  {
        //obtains user selected cobID value for processing

  }
```

Comment: Decorate your `Controller` method with `[HttpPost]` and change the return type to `ActionResult` and  `return new EmptyResult();` if you do not want to return a `View`. For such purposes, you would use `AJAX` to call your `void` method and then return back a response from the server.

Comment: Did you get this working?